# How to get data in mounted from axios call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

```
<ion-row class="cards-wrapper">
  <theme-card
    v-for="theme in filteredThemes"
    :router-link="`/theme/${theme.slug}`"
    :key="theme.id"
    :name="theme.name"
    :tags="theme.tags"
    :id="theme.id"
    :path="theme.image.path"
  ></theme-card>
</ion-row>


mounted() {
  this.getThemes();
  this.filteredThemes = this.themes;
  console.log(this.themes);
},


//in methods:

async getThemes() {
  await axios
    .get("url")
    .then((response) => (this.themes = response.data));
},
```

I tried using `async/await` but its not working right (probably I'm using it wrong), when I console log themes in mounted I don't get my data, I'd like to get data from my api call in mounted. I know this has something with asynchronicity, can u give me a hint what to do? Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still don't get data, try like this:

```
async mounted() {
  await this.getThemes();
  this.filteredThemes = this.themes;
},
```

//in methods:

```
async getThemes() {
  await axios
    .get("url")
    .then((response) => (this.themes = response.data));
},
```

Answer (score 0):

`.then((response) => (this.themes = response.data));`

using an arrow function changes what `this` is, i've seem some people writing it like:

```
const that = this;

await axios
  .get("url")
  .then((response) => (that.themes = response.data));
```

Comment: i edited my code, is it still right? i have my axios call in methods